# Publish a new web

Tags: 2013

Can anyone tell me how to publish a new publishing web in code please? I have created three new web from a site collection and would like to publish them as well.

Answer (score 2):

**With powerShell:**

```
if ((Get-PSSnapin "Microsoft.ShasrePoint.PowerShell" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) -eq $null) {
    Add-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell"
}

function PublishWelcomePage($webURL){
    $spWeb = Get-SPWeb -Identity $webURL 
    $folder = $spWeb.RootFolder
    $pageURL = $folder.WelcomePage
    $page = $spWeb.GetFile($pageUrl);
    $page.Publish("Page is Published!")
    $spWeb.Dispose
}
```

Comment: Sorry I should have stated in c# please and NOT a page a publishing WEB